# creating new data columns with mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the following data:

```
data <- data.frame(Name=c("11C","11C","12C","12C","20D","20D"),
               PID=c("AD15E","AD15E","AA05D","AA05D","Z48J","Z48J"),
               Type=c("Home","Auto","Home","Auto","Home","Auto"),
               Brand=c("A","B","C","H","I","D"),
               Model=c("A152","K235","W54","H2","A57","Y0878"))
```

Using mutate, I want to create four new columns in the dataframe (HomeBrand, HomeModel, AutoBrand, AutoModel) on the row where the first unique PID shows up.

The result should look like the following:

```
result <- data.frame(Name=c("11C","12C","20D"),
               PID=c("AD15E","AA05D","Z48J"),
               Type=c("Home","Home","Home"),
               HomeBrand=c("A","C","I"),
               HomeModel=c("A152","W54","A57"),
               AutoBrand=c("B","H","D"),
               AutoModel=c("K235","H2","Y0878"))
```

I've tried using mutate but can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make sense to have a *Type* column of *Home* in the result because the *Type* column goes to the header, and for each row you have mixed *Home* and *Auto* values; Without that column, its a simple task with `reshape`:

```
reshape(data, idvar = c("Name", "PID"), timevar = "Type", direction = "wide") 

#  Name   PID Brand.Home Model.Home Brand.Auto Model.Auto
#1  11C AD15E          A       A152          B       K235
#3  12C AA05D          C        W54          H         H2
#5  20D  Z48J          I        A57          D      Y0878
```

---

For comparison, this is your result:

```
result
#  Name   PID Type HomeBrand HomeModel AutoBrand AutoModel
#1  11C AD15E Home         A      A152         B      K235
#2  12C AA05D Home         C       W54         H        H2
#3  20D  Z48J Home         I       A57         D     Y0878
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), Name + PID  ~ Type, value.var = c("Brand", "Model"), sep="")
#   Name   PID BrandAuto BrandHome ModelAuto ModelHome
#1:  11C AD15E         B         A      K235      A152
#2:  12C AA05D         H         C        H2       W54
#3:  20D  Z48J         D         I     Y0878       A57
```